# jQuery UI - Custom widget - Datepicker to Whole Year Calendar

Tags: jquery-ui

i want to display whole year with jquery ui. is it possible to cut down the code to just whole year Calender?

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the "defaultDate" to the 1th of january, and then set "numberOfMonths" to 12.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#multiple-calendars

Edit: you don't have to set the defaultDate to 1th of january, it depends on the date you want the calender to start.